# Issues using jsonsimple with java(maven) in VScode

Tags: java, json, maven, visual-studio-code, noclassdeffounderror

I am rather new to VSCode and maven and am trying to work with a JSON file in java, i found out about json simple and decided to try it but i just cant get it to work.
The goal is to convert the json file (which contains a json array) into an object i can work with in java.

When i run the following code:

```java
package pandemic;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;



public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(".\\jsonfiles\\cities.json");
        
        Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray citiesInfo = (JSONArray) obj;
        System.out.println(citiesInfo.get(1));
    }
}
```

I get this message:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class pandemic.Game
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
```

I tried to use gson as well but got the same error.
I even went as far as to do a clean install of a new jdk to make sure that isnt the issue. No luck.
I checked my pom.xml many times and its the same as any example i have seen. Does anyone here know what i can do to fix this?

Edit: Have also tried updating the project and cleaning the java language and resetting the workspace.

Comment: try left click on pom.xml file and select "update project" then CTRL + SHIT + P  look for "Clean java language..." and reset workspace ( don't forget to check if you have extension "Extension Pack for Java" on your vscode and jdk 11+ installed )

Comment: @DilermandoLima Thank you for the response but these are things i now remember also trying already and just now tried to be sure, sadly they do not fix the issue.

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been resolved?

Comment: It has not been resolved and yes, i tried your anwser, thank you for your help still

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get it working, Why don't you ignore the ParseExeption file altogether ? Just try running the code with Generic Exceptions ?
You can focus on the ParseException when you get some experience working with the code.

Remove `import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;`
and change `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {` to `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {`

Comment: Thank you for your response and while a good idea it seems the issue is somehow in the dependency even though im sure its written corectly. I tried your solution and it lead me to the same error just with JSONParser.

I also apologize for the late reply, it has been a busy few days so i failed to check StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

When your project lacks needed dependency, java extension compiles `.java` file, then the error occurs. Add the following code in `pom.xml`, the extension **Maven for java** will rebuild project since it detects changes in `pom.xml`. After that, you may run `.java` file successfully.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.clerezza.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.json.simple</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.
The dependecy was already added as 
<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>

I still tried your code but it did not help sadly.

Comment: Also, sorry for the late reply, i was quite busy with other tasks and failed to check StackOverflow

Comment: but.. I havent solved it..